# Inconsistent permissions for different users in Cortana skill/bot

Tags: azure, botframework, cortana, cortana-skills-kit

I created and deployed a Node.js bot on my Azure account. I also added the Cortana channel with *Manage user identity through Connected Services* enabled and *Request user profile data* enabled (here I have `User.Info.Email` and `User.Info.Name`). The bot is shared with multiple people using groups (*Deployed to group* option in the Cortana dashboard).

If I'm logged-in into Cortana with the same email I use on Azure (where the bot is deployed) I get the auth window (since I enabled *Connected Services*) and then the following screen.

[image]

This is fine since that's how the bot should work.

But if I'm logged-in into Cortana with a different email (one of the emails from the Cortana dashboard group) I don't get the auth window and also some requested permissions are missing.

[image]

Are there more steps or requirements for sharing Cortana skills than just using the *Deployed to group* option?

Comment: Cortana currently only supports MSA accounts, and does not support AAD type accounts.  Is the account you're using in the 2nd scenerio an MSA account?

Comment: Yes, I'm using MSA accounts. If they weren't, I wouldn't even be able to share my Cortana skill.

Answer (score 0):

If you Deploy to Group first, then change your skill configuration, the deployed to group users will only see the first configuration you made.